# how to write a list of data in HTML table using python

Tags: python, html

I have build up a HTML table and want to write data using python code.
Here is the code:

```
 <body>
<h1 align="center">EXAMPLE</h1>
<table style="width:100%">


<tr>


<th width="17%" height="70">XYZ</th>
<th width="37%">XYZ</th>        
<th width="16%">XYZ</th>
<th width="16%">XYZ</th>
<th width="14%">XYZ</th>


</tr>

</table>
```

I want to enter the table data using strings and using python code. Is it possible to enter the data??

*Here these XYZ values shall be replaced by using string.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible ? But your question as such is very unclear , what data do you want to write ? Exactly *where* do you want to write (by this I am not asking about the th/tr in table , but where exactly this html resides ?

Comment: The HTML resides in a certain folder in my desktop. I want to write any data using string variable of Python. Say I want to write TRAIN LIST in the table header and want to replace this XYZ by TRAIN LIST. I want to import the HTML file into python and replace the XYZ by any other data.

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps

```
my_string = 'whatever you want'

with open('my.html') as html:
    html_data = html.read()
with open('new.html', 'w') as new_html:
    new_html.write(html_data.replace('XYZ', my_string))
```